# A proof involving linear ordering concept

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> > "Let $(P, <)$ and $(Q, \prec)$ be linearly ordered sets, and let $h$ be a one-to-one function with domain $P$ and range $Q$ such that $h(p_1)\prec h(p_2)$ whenever $p_1<p_2$. Then $h$ is an isomorphism between $(P,<)$ and $(Q,\prec )$.
> >
> > *Proof*. We have to verify that if $p_1, p_2 \in P$ are such that $h(p_1)\prec h(p_2)$, then $p_1<p_2$. But if $p_1$ is not less than $p_2$, then, because < is a linear ordering of $P$, either $p_1=p_2$ or $p_2<p_1$. If $p_1=p_2$, then $h(p_1)=h(p_2)$, and if $p_2<p_1$, then $h(p_2)\prec h(p_1)$, by the assumption. Either case contradicts $h(p_1)\prec h(p_2)$."

Since $<$ is a linear ordering, for all $p_1, p_2\in P$, either $p_1<p_2$ or $p_2<p_1$.
Why is $p_1=p_2$ treated as a separate case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is using *linear ordering* to mean what I would call a *strict linear order(ing)*. A binary relation $<$ on a set $A$ is a strict linear order if it is transitive and has the *trichotomy property*: for any $a,b\in A$, exactly one of $a<b$, $a=b$, and $b<a$ holds. The usual notions $<$ and $>$ in $\Bbb R$ are strict linear orders, while $\le$ and $\ge$ are what I would call simply linear orders.

Thus, the case $p_1=p_2$ really **is** a separate case.